# Verb for "... his passion"

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to add a verb into the following context:

> Ever since he was a child, he has been fascinated by the world of
>   computers. Now, he is seeking employement with a company where he can
>   **...** his passion.

However, no word comes to my mind which I could use. Neither does something come to my mind which I could Google in this case.

Edit: Came up with pursue, any other suggestions?

Comment: he is seeking employment with a company where ??? **I** ??? can ... his passion

Comment: “Any other suggestions” is not a proper SE question: it can have no right answer, just a popularity contest.

Comment: @ScotM Yes, I forgot to replace I with he there :| Initially I wrote everything in 1st person, but I didn't want to post the question like that :) Anyway, the rabit's out of the hat now.

Comment: We'll [chase one rabbit](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221136/is-there-an-english-idiom-for-trying-to-do-two-things-at-the-same-time-and-faili/221146#221146) at a time :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Fulfill](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fulfil?q=fulfill)* might work:

> verb (fulfills, fulfilling, fulfilled)
>
> 1.0 Achieve or realize (something desired, promised, or predicted):
>   *he wouldn’t be able to **fulfill** his ambition to visit Naples*
>
> 1.1 (fulfil oneself) Gain happiness or satisfaction by achieving one’s potential:
>
> ODO **Emphasis** mine

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *[indulge](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/indulge)*

> Allow oneself to enjoy the pleasure of

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: If this really is intended as an application for a job, I suggest you avoid the word "indulge", which suggests "indulgent" or "self-indulgent", i.e. you're doing it for fun, not for the good of the customer and your employer.

Comment: @ConcreteGannet Don't disagree. I think *pursue* might still be best.  *Fulfill* might also work.

Comment: Yes, this is for a job application.

Answer (score 2):

*... where **I** could **behold** **his** passion at work ...*

Is this the girl talking, or what? I thought it sounded Romance, thus my suggestion :-)

> Blackwood's Edinburgh Magazine - Volume 36 - Page 105 1834 - ‎Full
>   view
>
> I flew rather than ran along the bank, till I arrired opposite the
>   spot **where I could behold him** faintly struggling to disencumber
>   himself of the cloak, which impeded all his efforts, and would have
>   reduced him, in a very few minutes more, to a ...

Answer (score 2):

One may also "realize" a passion. This is the verb I would use in the case of a fascination becoming practice and employment.

Answer (score 1):

*...where I could [sate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sate) his passion.*

```
 verb
 1 Satisfy (a desire or an appetite) to the full: 
   sate your appetite at the resort’s restaurant
```

Comment: where ***he*** can sate his passion... EDIT: Ahh, I see the OP has been edited and corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Given the context... Appreciate, respect, come to terms with, rely on.

Answer (score 1):

Further his passion could be used in this context